# Comparing reals in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My current method of comparing two reals (after calculations) is to take the difference and cast to an integer and compare to 0, for example (just to highlight the problem, example might work in simulator)

```
variable a : real := 0.1;
constant epsilon : real := 1.0E-5; -- Whatever accuracy needed, not too low though
a := a + 5.3;

assert a = 5.4;                -- Yields intermitent errors
assert integer(a - 5.4) = '0'; -- Erroneous if 4.8 < a < 5.9 due to cast rounding
assert abs(a - 5.4) < epsilon;    -- Will work everytime, but seems a bit forced
```

The reason for this way is that I got a lot of assertion errors in an testbench I wrote (a tad more complext then the example code). I was accounting these errors as floating point errors in GHDL simulator. Is there a better way to compare two reals to each other, like using machine epsilon, or any build in methods?

Comment: No it doesn't work like a charm every time... add `assert integer(a-5.3) = 0; assert (a-5.5) = '0';` to your testbench... See also Prof Kahan's papers on floating point - this may not be the best one, but www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf

Comment: @brian-drummond That is very true, but it at least gets rid of the floating point errors in this case, which is ok for my easy testbench but of course not good enough. An better approach would perhaps be to define `constant epsilon : real := 0.00001` and then `assert a - 5.4 < epsilon` . But my question still remains, is there a good way to do this or is this the best?

Comment: assert abs(a-5.4) < epsilon;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is generic to any programming language that uses "real" values (a.k.a. floating point numbers).

The standard way to compare reals in automatic tests is to define an small value epsilon. Then check that the absolute difference between your two reals is less than epsilon. You can define your own procedure `assertEqual(x,y, epsilon)` if you want to write concise test benches.

```
procedure assertEquals(
    x, y    : real; epsilon : real := 1.0E-5;
    message : string               := "";
    level   : severity_level       := error) is
begin
    assert (abs (x - y) < epsilon) report message severity level;
end procedure assertEquals;
```

Comment: Maybe the allowed deviation should be based on the magnitude of the operands, since assertEquals(1.0E-6, 2.0E-6) will not raise an assert.  Scaling, for example based on change in units, should not cause different compare.  One possibility is to allow a deviation as fraction of `abs(x) + abs(y)`.

Comment: The size of type real is specified differently prior to IEEE Std 1076-2008 - 3.1.4.1 Predefined floating point types, -2002 and earlier, - 1.0 E38 to + 1.0 E38 inclusive; 5.2.5 Floating-point types, 5.2.5.1 General, conforms either to IEEE Std 754-1985 or to IEEE Std 854-1987, minimum representation size of 64 bits. Your epsilon could be tool standard version or implementation dependent. Also see package float_pkg for design specification targeted and synthesis eligible floating point representation. In package math_real epsilon values are used in the cordic function with a precision factor.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @Philippe, comparison of reals requires some margin to account for limited precision and accumulated errors in the least significant bits. Using a simple epsilon value is one common way to do this but it has a limitation in that its value is absolute in relation to the numbers being compared. You need to know in advance the expected values you're comparing to pick a suitable epsilon.

If the set of numbers you need to compare covers a wide range of magnitudes you end up with an epsilon that is too large for properly comparing small values. In this situation you'd want a small epsilon when comparing small reals and a larger epsilon for larger numbers. This is accomplished by using a comparison that accounts for relative error.

[This page](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) gives a good overview of a method that allows comparison of reals using relative error rather than absolute error. The following function is an implementation of the relative comparison in VHDL:

```
-- Adapted from: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/
function relatively_equal(a, b, epsilon : real) return boolean is
begin
  if a = b then -- Take care of infinities
    return true;
  elsif a * b = 0.0 then -- Either a or b is zero
    return abs(a - b) < epsilon ** 2;
  else -- Relative error
    return abs(a - b) / (abs(a) + abs(b)) < epsilon;
  end if;
end function;
```

Here the epsilon parameter is a fraction that specifies the number of significant digits to compare for relative equality.

```
-- Compare for relative equality to three significant digits
-- These are all considered equal while using the same epsilon parameter
assert relatively_equal(1.001, 1.002, 1.0E-3) report "1.001 != 1.002";
assert relatively_equal(100.1, 100.2, 1.0E-3) report "100.1 != 100.2";
assert relatively_equal(1001.0, 1002.0, 1.0E-3) report "1001 != 1002";

-- Compare for relative equality to four significant digits
-- This will raise the assertion
assert relatively_equal(1.001, 1.002, 1.0E-4) report "1.001 != 1.002";
```